# Improving Article Classifier Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I've built an article classifier based on Wikipedia data that I fetch, which comes from 5 total classifications.

They are:

```
Finance (15 articles) [1,0,0,0,0]
Sports (15 articles) [0,1,0,0,0]
Politics (15 articles) [0,0,1,0,0]
Science (15 articles) [0,0,0,1,0]
None (15 random articles not pertaining to the others) [0,0,0,0,1]
```

I went to wikipedia and grabbed about 15 pretty lengthy articles from each of these categories to build my corpus that I could use to train my network.

After building a lexicon of about 1000 words gathered from all of the articles, I converted each article to a `word vector`, along with the correct `classifier` label.

The word vector is a `hot array`, while the label is a `one hot array`.

For example, here is the representation of one article:

```
[
 [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,... > 1000], [1,0,0,0] # this maps to Finance
]
```

So, in essence, I have this randomized list of `word vectors` mapped to their correct `classifiers`.

My network is a 3 layer, deep neural net that contains 500 nodes on each layer. I pass through the network over 30 epochs, and then just display how accurate my model is at the end.

Right now, Im getting about 53% to 55% accuracy. My question is, what can I do to get this up into the 90's? Is it even possible, or am I going to go crazy trying to train this thing?

Perhaps additionally, what is my main bottleneck so to speak?

**edited per comments below**

Neural networks aren't really designed to run best on single machines, they work much better if you have a cluster, or at least a production-grade machine. It's very common to eliminate the "long tail" of a corpus - if a term only appears in one document one time, then you may want to eliminate it. You may also want to apply some stemming so that you don't capture multiples of the same word. I strongly advise to you try applying TFIDF transformation to your corpus before pruning.

Network size optimization is a field unto itself. Basically, you try adding more/less nodes and see where that gets you. See the following for a technical discussion.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to know without seeing the data.

Things to try:

Transform your word vector to TFIDF. Are you removing stop words? You can add bi-grams/tri-grams to your word vector.

Add more articles - it could be difficult to separate them in such a small corpus. The length of a specific document doesn't necessarily help, you want to have more articles.

30 epochs feels very low to me.

Comment: Okay, so I removed stop words, but my lexicon is enormous unless I apply some type of filtering to it. The lexicon is over 35000 words. Should I just pass the entire thing in and wait an hour or further filter it? Im going to blow up my macbook pro haha

As for the rest, Ill do that and see what happens!

Comment: One more question on the layers. How do I optimize the amount of neurons I should put in the hidden layers? How do I even know how many layers I should use? It seems that they also have massive impacts on the accuracy of the model.